# docker: push image not work

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I setup a private docker registry in my one server(let's call it server-1). I can push and pull image in this server successfully.
server-1: Docker version 1.7.1

```
kuankr-staging@kuankrstaging-OptiPlex-390:~$ docker push docker.agutong.com:5000/registry
The push refers to a repository [docker.agutong.com:5000/registry] (len: 1)
2f1ef7702586: Image already exists 
97cf055388e0: Image successfully pushed 
8703b7c675b1: Image successfully pushed 
4f780ec6d926: Image successfully pushed 
db95df628950: Image successfully pushed 
a5f051f1f664: Image successfully pushed 
2d449bb18c75: Image successfully pushed 
8251da35e7a7: Image successfully pushed 
e5855facec0b: Image successfully pushed 
5bff21ba5409: Image successfully pushed 
6071b4945dcf: Image successfully pushed 
Digest: sha256:45671274c462f148a968d4c867ff70cfd34f0a913b3a4bcdd0870dab396f32d1
```

Things go well here.
Then I want to push another server image to this registry. Let's call it server-2. server-2: Docker version 1.3.1. server-1 and server-2 are in the same local network.

```
$ docker images
docker.agutong.com:5000/agutong_base latest  75606af212f5 12 months ago
```

and I run

`docker push docker.agutong.com:5000/agutong_base`

It prints:

```
The push refers to a repository [docker.agutong.com:5000/agutong_base] (len: 1)
Sending image list
2015/08/14 18:44:57
```

These output looks like different with successful `push`. I believe it break down.

If I pull preceding `docker.agutong.com:5000/registry` which can be pulled successfully in server-1, it also doesn't work.

```
$ docker pull docker.agutong.com:5000/registry:latest
Pulling repository docker.agutong.com:5000/registry
2015/08/14 18:51:59 Error: image registry not found
```

In summary, `pull` and `push` work well in server-1 but not in server-2.

Answer (score 0):

When I push or pull in server-2, docker-registry logs 404 records:

```
192.168.1.152 - - [14/Aug/2015:12:34:41 +0000] "GET /v1/_ping HTTP/1.1" 404 19 "" "curl/7.35.0"
192.168.1.152 - - [14/Aug/2015:12:34:59 +0000] "GET /v1/ping HTTP/1.1" 404 19 "" "curl/7.35.0"
192.168.1.152 - - [14/Aug/2015:12:35:02 +0000] "GET /v1/search HTTP/1.1" 404 19 "" "curl/7.35.0"
192.168.1.152 - - [14/Aug/2015:12:36:10 +0000] "GET /v1/_ping HTTP/1.1" 404 19 "" "Go 1.1 package http"
192.168.1.152 - - [14/Aug/2015:12:36:10 +0000] "PUT /v1/repositories/agutong_base/ HTTP/1.1" 404 19 "" "docker/1.3.1 go/go1.3.3 git-commit/4e9bbfa kernel/3.13.0-24-generic os/linux arch/amd64"
192.168.1.152 - - [14/Aug/2015:12:40:41 +0000] "GET /v1/_ping HTTP/1.1" 404 19 "" "Go 1.1 package http"
192.168.1.152 - - [14/Aug/2015:12:40:41 +0000] "GET /v1/repositories/registry/images HTTP/1.1" 404 19 "" "docker/1.3.1 go/go1.3.3 git-commit/4e9bbfa kernel/3.13.0-24-generic os/linux arch/amd64"
```

Maybe I need upgrade docker in server-2